# Is $1+T$ a topological generator for $Z_{p}[[T]]$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, topological-groups, p-adic-groups, p-adic-numbers

Consider the ring of formal power series $\mathbb{Z}_p[[T]]$ (where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ denotes the ring of $p$-adic integers) with the topology in which a neighborhood basis for $0$ is given by the ideals $I_{n,m} = \left<p^n,T^m\right>$. Is $1+T$ a topological generator for $\mathbb{Z}_p[[T]]$ (i.e., is $\mathbb{Z}_p[[T]]$ the minimal closed subring containing $1+T$)?

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: So this site is not for homework questions. You might try posting on math.stackexchange.com, but you would need to explain what you have tried already, rather than just ask for an answer.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440622/is-1t-a-topological-generator-for-z-pt

Comment: This is not a hoework. I was reading about standard Iwasawa algebras and the authors made a claim that trying to understand which I asked this question. And this is my first question on Overflow. I'm sorry I didn't know Overflow was for researchers. Noted.

Comment: Possibly helpful question: What topology have you put on this ring?

Comment: With the topology introduced in the edit, it suffices to show that for any translate of $I_{n,m}$ there is a polynomial in $1+T$ that lies in that open set.  Further explanation can be sought at Math.SE.

Comment: The minimal closed subring containing $1+T$ must surely be the minimal closed subring containing $T$.